# How to stop changing ip during request

Tags: ip-address

After like 30-40 seconds ip changes, basically after I already opened a page on a website and want to go to another. So at that point the website can just block the new ip, then I have to restart tor again.
I wonder whos' the "genius" that thought changing ip during request is a good idea,and no option to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LongLivingPorts` for your *destination* port **and** to tweak the time of the long living connections in `torrc` - then just restart your Tor or reflect the changes through the Tor Control Protocol commands - and it will work as you want it